# Data augmentation by random rotation in Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection-api, data-augmentation

object detection api only has random_rotation90. I want to increase the data with 10, 20, 30, ... 90 degree rotation for all images. How can I do this?

Comment: This repo looks promising:  https://github.com/JinLuckyboy/TensorFlowObjectDetectionAPI-with-imgaug/tree/main/object_detection (from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2336).  I have not tried it but the changes are both recent and appear minimal.